# Raspberry Pi and Java Installation

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to install Oracle's Java jdk and compile and run java programs on my Raspberry pi. Basically I am getting a ***Error: Could not find or load main class*** error when I try to run a **java myfile.java**.

The steps I took were:

1. Downloaded "wheezy" from the Raspberry Pi website that allows java (soft float)
2. Downloaded the arm jdk from Oracle's website
3. Used the command `tar -zxvf jdk-7u6-linux-arm-sfp.gz` to unzip the jdk
4. Wrote, compiled, and then attempted to run a simple java program

On a side note, because the wheezy image was only 2GB, I partitioned the other 2GB of my 4GB SD card for some additional storage. That is where I unzipped my jdk and now when I want to run **java** or **javac** I have to use the full path. How can you modify the installation so that you can simply type in **java** with out the full path. Doesn't that have something to do with where the binaries are installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry... it was as simple as removing the **.class** from the ***java myfile.class***

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem then you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 4):

The JRE sounds like it's installed ok but you need to compile your java before you can run it. As the Pi is relatively slow, use your PC/Mac to compile your app:

`javac myfile.java`

Then you can copy myfile.class, which should contain a main method, to your Pi and run:

`java your.package.name.myfile`

You can test this on your PC/Mac (or Linux :) ) before copying to your Pi.

Your other issue is resolved by adding java to the PATH. Edit /etc/profile, and add:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/jdk/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that Oracle JDK of version 7 is actually JRE, so it doesn't include Java compiler. So you have two options hare:
1. Either borrow tools.jar from JDK installed on some desktop machine
2. Or install JDK 1.8 early access.
I strongly recommend to do second option with several benefits:
1. JDK 1.8 is complete JDK so you can compile, for example I run JSP pages without precompilation
2. JDK 1.8 is hard point so you are not limited to wheeze soft point, for example I use Arch Linux.
I also created getting started document you can find useful:
http://tjws.sourceforge.net/arch-raspi-java8.html
Enjoy your Raspberry PI

Answer (score 1):

You can install the full JDK now also, there is a tar file on the Oracle download site for ARM.